# Big Query 'internal error occurred...' on valid query to create view

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a valid SQL query in Big Query which executes fine when run. However, Big Query tells me 'an internal error occurred and the request could not be completed' under the validator and as such I cannot save the query as a view.

Why is this? It's very frustrating and it hasn't happened with other queries I've written. I've double checked all the schema references are fully defined etc. It's been happening for the past 3 days now.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome - can you share the query please?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that! It's a pretty massive query and I'd have to obfuscate some of it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say that it runs fine, but you cannot run it under the validator? Where is ti running fine?

Comment: When I execute the query it executes absolutely fine and generates results. However, the validator shows the red exclamation mark and says 'An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed', preventing the select statement from being saved as a view.

Comment: This is still happening. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest raising this with Google support directly, if you are unable to share the query it is hard to diagnose, but it sounds like a bug!